# Почему функция ничего не возращает

Tags: javascript

Есть такой вызов функции:

```
cornerstone.loadAndCacheImage(file).then(function(image) {
      console.log(image);
});
```

Не выводится ничего, хотя если взять саму функцию:

```
function loadAndCacheImage(imageId) {
    if(imageId === undefined) {
        throw "loadAndCacheImage: parameter imageId must not be undefined";
    }

    var imagePromise = cornerstone.imageCache.getImagePromise(imageId);
    if(imagePromise !== undefined) {
        return imagePromise;
    }

    imagePromise = loadImageFromImageLoader(imageId);

    if(imagePromise === undefined) {
        throw "loadAndCacheImage: no image loader for imageId";
    }

    cornerstone.imageCache.putImagePromise(imageId, imagePromise);

    return imagePromise;
}
```

Даже если перед `return` написать:

```
console.log(imagePromise);
```

То выведется информация, но возвращаться ничего не хочет.

Comment: Сложно что-то ответить, если в листинге нет используемых зависимостей. Т. е. что за `cornerstone.imageCache.getImagePromise(imageId)`, например? Что возвращает и что ожидалось? P. S. Вы вызываете функцию как метод, хотя вроде это не метод.

Comment: там идет переопределение - cornerstone.loadAndCacheImage = loadAndCacheImage;

Comment: проблема не в том, что оно не возвращает то что надо, а в том, что в середине функции оно что то возвращает, но return не возвращает ничего